# EF5 Codefirst Seeding From XML File

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework, ef-code-first, connection-string

I'm currently using EF5 to connect to SQL Server 2012 Express and have got to the stage where a large amount of repeatable Seed Data would be good for testing purposes. I already have a (self-created, from another project) tool which just needs a little tweaking to output a large amount of XML seed data.

What would be really nice would be, in my C# Seed function, simply to pass a connection string to my DbContext class to enable it to import all the data from the XML file, using the same POCO classes I use for my Model. I could then simply copy all the data in to my standard DbContext (parameterless initialisation, connects to SQL Server).

I can deal with copying the data and outputting it to SQL Server, but is it even possible to specify a connection string to import the seed data from an XML file in this way?

Comment: Why are you not using common `Seed` method in database initializer or in migrations? Those already offers you a crated context instance initialized with correct connection string.

Comment: I am. That offers a context for the *target* database. What I'm asking here is how to use the same CodeFirst objects to extract the *source* data from an XML file (without writing new POCO classes).